# Is there a CSS sprite generator that also gives retina -versions?

Tags: css, sprite, retina-display

If there already isn't one, I would very much appreciate if someone could give some instructions on how to make a retina and non-retina CSS-sprite myself. Preferably using some CSS sprite -generator in the process if possible.

Related to topic: http://miekd.com/articles/using-css-sprites-to-optimize-your-website-for-retina-displays/

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I know this thread is old but another alternate if you need retina support, optional CSS embedding and/or JSON output: https://www.facetstudios.com/sprite-generator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Method 1

[Here's a Mixin](https://gist.github.com/alanhogan/2878758) to achieve this with [Compass](http://compass-style.org/)

## Method 2

1. Create two version of your image files, one for "regular" density screens, the other for retina screens, with pictures twice the resolution. (Meaning if one of the pictures is 23px by 41 px, the retina version would be 46px by 28 px)
2. Go to http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ and create two versions of your sprite image. Lets assume your images have a smaller dimension than 25px. Choose Horizontal Offset: 25px in the first non-retina version, and 50px in the retina version. Save your sprites as sprite.png and spritex2.png
3. In your css file you can now define something along the rough lines of:

   ```
   .#spriteA,spriteB{
        background-image: url(sprite.png);
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
    }        

   @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
   only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
   only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi) {
   .#spriteA,spriteB{
        background-image: url(spriteX2.png);
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
    }
   }

   .spriteA{ background-position: 0 50%; }
   .spriteB{ background-position: -31px 50%; }
   ```

This way, the background position ratio (50%) is maintained whether you using the non-retina or retina resolutions.

Comment: Thank you very much OpherV! 

Still, after spending some time getting a load of error messages in terminal with every one of the ruby and Compass -installs, I'm afraid I'm still too much of a designer and not enough tech-savvy to handle this option...

If there are no easier alternatives, I'll of course have to look into it more deeply.

Comment: Well, at least you've tried :) Let me update my answer with some other alternative

Answer (score 2):

Here is another online tool for creating low & hiDef retina sprite: [cssspritegenerator.net](http://cssspritegenerator.net)

Can also produce webp image, and with bigger image comes bigger size, so we need to reduce them back to @1-size sprite with better image format ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are some task managers, mixins and online generators for this objective. I personally use grunt as a task manager and [Sprite Smith](https://github.com/Ensighten/grunt-spritesmith) as a module on some of my projects.

I also use http://www.retinaspritegenerator.com for quick sprite generation with retina support. It also has a selection of sequence algorithms like Sprite Smith.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but adding this response in case it helps others with similar questions.

I made some updates to the [smartsprites](http://csssprites.org/) tool to be able to support retina sprites. With this tool, you essentially annotate your CSS with directives telling the tool which images to sprite, run the tool, and it will generate the sprite images and modified CSS to reference the new images.

This tool gives you fine grained support over which images are sprited, how the sprites are laid out, and per-image sprite padding, among other things. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are some amazing retina sprite generators out there. I recently used a couple of them which I personally love.
1. [Sprites](http://jcwhatever.com/retina-css-sprite-generator/)
2. [Sprite box](http://www.spritebox.net/)
3. [Retina Sprites](http://www.retinaspritegenerator.com/)
4. [Zero Sprites](http://zerosprites.com/)
5. [Sprite Generator](http://paulrhayes.com/sprite-generator/)

As mentioned in the previous answer, [Sprite Smith](https://github.com/Ensighten/grunt-spritesmith) is one more awesome generator.